# Pass queryset data to another query django

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have the following model. I am trying to select all from UserClasses where a specific class_id is specified. I then want to get the User data for each of the results

```
class UserClasses(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This is my django view where I am trying to pull all User objects:

```
users = UserClasses.objects.filter(class_id=data['class_id'])
user_details = User.objects.filter(#get users.id from userclasses and compare here)
```

How can I pass the results from one queryset into another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `__in` operator combined with the `values_list()` method of Django to achieve what you want.

```
users = UserClasses.objects.filter(class_id=data['class_id'])
user_details = User.objects.filter(id__in=users.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Comment: Sweet! I just tried it though and it's only returning 1 user. There is multiple users returned from the first query.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to pass 'user_id' into values_list()